# Get Widget Updated manually with UserDefault Data

Tags: xcode, swiftui, widgetkit

It's my first time trying to implement a widget in an existing app. Till now i created most of the UI/UX through storyboard. So it's my first time using SwiftUi as well. Now I created a widget displaying a circle progress bar. But i can't get the data to update. I tried everything i found online but it still doesn't work.
Is it right that userDefault doesn't work without app groups? (I can't create app groups yet because I haven't joined the apple developer program yet)
Is there another relatively easy way to give data to a widget (for example from firestore)?

In AppDelegate I defined a new key with a value 0.1.
Now every time a special view appears 0.1 is added and the timeline should be refreshed.
I only want the widget to update manually (WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()).
this is my timeline Code:

```
struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {

    
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        let widgetMessageInt = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "testIntMessage")
        return SimpleEntry(date: Date(), testInt: 0.5)
    }

    func getSnapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let widgetMessageInt = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "testIntMessage")
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(),testInt: 0.7)
        completion(entry)
    }

    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent,in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

        // Generate a timeline consisting of five entries an hour apart, starting from the current date.
        let widgetMessageInt = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "testIntMessage")
        let currentDate = Date()
       /* for minOffset in 0 ..< 2 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: minOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate,testInt: testInt)
            entries.append(entry)
        }*/


        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: currentDate,testInt: widgetMessageInt as! Double)
        entries.append(entry)
        
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
        
    }
}
```

In the small widget it should take the value and give it to the progressbar:

```
struct SmallWidget : View {
    @State var textColor: Color = .gray
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    var body: some View {
        Color.white
            .opacity(1)
            .overlay(
        HStack{
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 15){
                ZStack(alignment: .center){
                    CircularProgressView(progress: testInt, textColor: textColor, size: 16, textDone: "fertig", textSize: 22)
                        .frame(width: 90, height: 90)
                }
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: nil){
                    Text("Erreiche 100% um deine Streak fortzusetzen!")
                        .font(.system(size: 11, design: .rounded))
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                }
                
            }
            
        }.padding()
            .background(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.black.opacity(0.9) : Color.white)
        )
    }
}
```

I don´t know where the mistake is.
Maybe i forgot to add the needed Memberships? (Which are needed?)

Thanks in advance for your help!

P.S. Sorry for my bad english; it's not my native language

Comment: Widgets are like a gif and an entry is like a single image in the gif. Widgets doing listen or observed they must be reloaded each time there is an update. A good way to understand the concept is to make all the variables in the widget `let`, your widget doesn't show the declaration for `testInt` so I am assuming that you are using some unorthodox setup to pass the value. Also, yes if you want the main app to communicate with the widget extension you have to have a common storage area which in most cases is an app group.

Comment: OK thanks. Which is another way to transfer the data to the timeline provider (instead of userdefaults eg.)? Directly taking it from firebase? And if, do you know a good tutorial to learn this?

Comment: The only tutorial I've ever looked at for this is the Widget Code Along from Apple.  Just make sure any data retrieval happens in `getTimeline` it won't work anywhere else, if the data doesn't exist at that point it won't exist at any other point.

Comment: @loremipsum Ok that's the tutorial i've watched multiple times but i still don't understand how the data gets to the widget. He already has a struct for the widget view so he  directly uses that, ok. But i can't from where and where he get's his data. In his getTimeline he only creates 5 views for every hour connected with a date. Does he only needs the date (at least in part one)? For what is the simply entry, when the data needs to be in the get timeline ?

Comment: Look at the sample files you can get the code there. If I remember correctly he is getting it from a file in the project. It’s been a while I followed it when it was released for the wwdc.

Comment: Thanks! Now with sample data it works. But now I want to get data from firestore. But I can't import the Firebase Pod to the widget extension. Do I have do connect it somewhere special, or is it the wrong way to create a func in the extension which gets this data from the cloud? If, how can I get access on the struct from my main app?

Comment: Try with SPM, I’ve never tried but I wouldn’t expect results with cocoa pods

Comment: Like Lorem has suggested you could try Swift Package Manager. Extension target is similar to app target but has some differences. Extensions don't have access to the app's sandbox, that is why you need to create App Groups so that you can have a shared resources (like DB) that your extension can access. Your app has access to it's own sandbox as well as shared resources